# http tileLayer wms over https site forces in Chrome is forced to https

Tags: google-chrome, https, leaflet, wms

Just posted an [issue in leaflet's github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7337), but maybe is more related to the Chrome browser.
The problem:

- My site is HTTPS, and I'm using an HTTP WMS service. The WMS service doesn't have HTTPS support.

On load, the WMS layer gets forced to HTTPS which gives 404.

This only happens on Chrome; Firefox keeps calling the HTTP endpoint, thus working as expected.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/C3OIwptyhzCQ6h0x

```
L.tileLayer.wms("http://ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?", {
    layers: "IGNBaseOrto"
}).addTo(map)
L.tileLayer.wms("http://servicios.internet.ine.es/WMS/WMS_INE_SECCIONES_G01/MapServer/WMSServer", {
    layers: "Secciones2019",
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: 'Instituto Nacional de Estadística',
    version: '1.3.0'
}).addTo(map)
```

Any help?